# Private Field Error Not Defined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, class, babeljs, eslint, private

I'm attempting to use private class fields in NodeJS. I'm running this code through a ES-Lint with babel-parser and Babel. In VS Code, I have ES Lint showing the error. The error is listed below. It occurs during the assignment inside the IORedis constructor's authentication object. I also get the same error when I run the code in Babel.

> Parsing error: Private name #password is not defined

```
class MyRedis {
  constructor(password, host) {

    this.host = host || process.env.HOST;
    this.#password = password || process.env.PASSWORD;

    if (!this.#password) { throw new Error('Password not set'); }

    this.client = new IORedis({
      // removed some items for brevity
      host: this.host,
      password: this.#password // error is here
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to declare the private instance variable without `this` at the top of the class. You must include the `hash` as it's part of the name itself. See more information in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_instance_fields).

```
class MyRedis {
  #password; // declaration creates the private variable this.#password

  constructor(password, host) {

    this.host = host || process.env.HOST;
    this.#password = password || process.env.PASSWORD;

    this.client = new IORedis({
      // removed some items for brevity
      host: this.host,
      password: this.#password
    });
  }
}
```